# Generate installation logs

Tags: nsis

I am using special logging build to generate installation logs.
I have observed the logs are not generating when called another installer from installer script.
For ex -
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\installer1.exe" /S _?=$INSTDIR'

The log is generating for main installer but not for installer1.exe

The installer1.exe contains lots of components and I need to print the logs for the same. I have tried enabling logset on in the installer1 script but no luck.
Tried using dumplog but it doesn't work with silent installation.

Any help would be appreciated!

Sample code from Main Installer script --
InstallDir "C:\MyFolder"
Name "${PRODUCT_NAME_VERSION}"
OutFile "${OUT_FILE}"

Section "Test"
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
LogSet on
ExecWait '"$EXEDIR\Packages\installer1.exe" /S /INST=$INSTDIR' $0
SectionEnd

Sample code from sub-installer script ---
InstallDir "C:\MyFolder"
Section "-Demo"
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
LogSet on
LogText "Print something"
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\ExternalFolder\Demo
File /nonfatal /a /r $INSTDIR\ExternalFolder\Demo\Test
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\ExternalFolder\Demo\Test\TestSetup.exe" /silent '
SectionEnd

The sub-installer (installer1.exe) is pre-compiled and kept the exe in $EXEDIR\Packages\installer1.exe The patch is valid.

Answer (score 0):

_?= is special syntax that is only supported by NSIS uninstallers, installers use /D=.

```
ExecWait '"$InstDir\installer.exe" /S /D=$InstDir'
```

Logging of course has to be enabled in this sub-installer as well.

/D= overrides the InstallDir attributes, forcing $InstDir to the specified path before .onInit is executed.

`InstallDir $INSTDIR` does not make sense, use something like `InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"`

Comment: Thanks Anders! I posted wrong command in the question. Sorry. The command which I have used is ExecWait '"$EXEDIR\Packages\installer1.exe /S /INST=$INSTDIR'                                       Also, logging is enabled in sub installer. After changing /INST to /D in the above command, I am getting the error that Installation path entered is empty and it is aborting sub installer Installation. Could you please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Sorry for posting the answers instead editing the post. I have edited the post to include the sample Code. The installer1.exe is pre compiled and kept in the specified location - $EXEDIR\Packages\installer1.exe     And when changing the command :  ExecWait '"$InstDir\installer.exe" /S /D=$InstDir' It is throwing error saying  Installation directory path entered is empty, Aborting Installation for sub installer.

Comment: I edited the InstallDir as "C:\MyFolder". But same error exists as mentioned in above comments.